# Right align text in an HTML.TextBoxFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap, with ASP.Net MVC.

How can I right-align the text in the TextBoxFor:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PaymentReceived, 
new { @class = "pmtallocated pull-right" , .dir = "rtl" })
```

I get the error `Invalid expression term '.'` when trying above.

Thank you,

Mark

Comment: Does your `pmtallocated pull-right` CSS class have the property `direction:RTL;`?  If so, you don't need the `.dir = "rtl"` code in your Razor code.

Comment: Hi -thanks - but all that I needed to do was use @ instead of .dir!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try

```
new { @class = "pmtallocated pull-right" , @dir = "rtl" })
```

Answer (score 7):

Try any

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PaymentReceived, 
new { @class = "pmtallocated pull-right" , @dir = "rtl" })
```

or

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PaymentReceived, 
new { @class = "pmtallocated pull-right" , @style="text-align:right"})
```